# What will be the complexity of the neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

if neural network has x hidden layers with sizes from R1,R2...R(x), and size of input and output layer equal to one. How can I show that the complexity at most will be equal to product of
`2^(x+1)*(R1* R2*R3*...*Rx)`